# pointing to mysql-includes, trying to configure sphinx search

Tags: linux, centos, sphinx, putty

As I attempt to configure Sphinx Search, I get the following, which I'm sure many have seen before....

(Using Cent OS on a Linux VPS. Sphinx tarball has been downloaded and unpacked.)

```
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

Check that you do have MySQL include files installed.
The package name is typically 'mysql-devel'.

If include files are installed on your system, but you are still getting
this message, you should do one of the following:

1) either specify includes location explicitly, using --with-mysql-includes;
2) or specify MySQL installation root location explicitly, using --with-mysql;
3) or make sure that the path to 'mysql_config' program is listed in
your PATH environment variable.

To disable MySQL support, use --without-mysql option.
```

So, I ran `# which mysql-includes` to locate that, and here is what I got...

`/usr/bin/which: no mysql-devel in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)`

That may as well be an alien language, and now I'm stuck. I know that MySQL is installed on my server because I have DB's that are set up and being used. Can anyone help me over this hurdle?

Also, what's a good example of how to use something like `--with-mysql-includes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

This will grab the mysql development package from the CentOS repo's